# What does << in C# mean and is there a SQL equivalent?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

Can someone explain what the << is doing in this function:

```
return (b & (1 << pos)) != 0;
```

And is there an equivalent to this in T-SQL?

Comment: Bitwise shift - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx

Comment: Google `<<` in C# first.

Comment: @herohuyongtao I tried and nothing came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<` in C# means "shift number left". You can simulate it by multiplying by a corresponding power of two:

```
b & POWER(2, pos) <> 0
```

Comment: Note that this might result in overflow...  unlike in C#.

Comment: @PinnyM Of course it can! Same goes for the shift operator, though: shifting by a number that exceeds the number of bits is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: I should have clarified, it might result in an overflow _error_, unlike C# (where it will simply discard the higher bits).  Certainly they can both overflow.  The masking approach, however, would avoid the error for T-SQL.

Comment: What's meant by the masking approach? Definitely just got an overflow.

Comment: @endyourif - see [this series](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/tags/bitmasks/default.aspx) on bitmasks and SQL by Adam Machnic.  I'm not advocating that you take this approach as far as he did, but the concept of a function returning a bitmask table makes such operations much more reliable in SQL.

Answer (score 4):

It's [bitwise shift](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx).

Shift is not mentioned on [Bitwise Operators (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) page so I would say they are not awailable in TSQL. However, **bitwise shift in 2-based numeric system is equivalent to multiplying by 2**, so you can use that to perform similar operation without actually using bitwise shift.